# How to split a string that doesn't have whitespaces or any other non-letters in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, split

For example: `"thisIsSpinalTap"` should return the string `this-is-spinal-tap`
I keep thinking but just can't get through it
I tried this

```js
function isUpper(str)
{
  return str === str.toUpperCase();
}

function spinalCase(str) {
 
  let s=str.split('');
  let string=str.split('');

  for(var i=0;i<str.split('').length;i++)
  {
    if(isUpper(string[i]))
    {
        string.splice(i-1, 0, " ");
    }
      console.log(string)
  }
  return str;
}

spinalCase('thisIsSpinalTap');
```

(I tried to add space behind Upper-Case characters)
but the results were chaotic and I still don't know how will I even implement this

Comment: One reason for "results being chaotic" would be not rewinding `i` when you splice out a character... Also, why `str` _and_ `string`? You only need one.

Comment: @AKX i dont get it when u say rewind the `i`